# Can I use a server adapter card for GigE cameras on an industrial PC?

Tags: networking

I am building a machine vision system (gigabit ethernet cameras made by Basler), and need 5 network inputs into my industrial PC. Due to bandwidth and IP address concerns, I can't use a network switch into a single network port.

I can't seem to find many PCI Express, non-Power over Ethernet, Gigabit Ethernet, 4-port network adapter cards that aren't labeled "Server Adapter". I don't need support for teams, virtual machines, security, etc as this machine will not be internet-enabled.

Given that my other requirements are met (Intel chipset, support for jumbo frames) can I use a "Server Adapter" card for simple networking of cameras into an industrial PC?

EDIT:

The IP address thing seems to be a tripping point. I don't have a complete response for you; that tidbit came from a coworker was recently working on a similar machine with 2 linescan cameras and said that he had to jump through a number of hoops setting up separate subnets so that they would both be recognized. I'm (plainly) not a network guy so his explanation only made partial sense to me, and he's out this week.

Really, all I'm trying to ask is whether [this question](https://communities.intel.com/thread/11999) is relevant to what I'm trying to do, and is there any reason a server adapter card, with its extra features, wouldn't do something a regular desktop adapter can do?

EDIT 2:

I mistakenly thought that IP cameras and GigE cameras were more similar than they are. I updated the title to reflect this. They aren't IP cameras in the same sense as most surveillance cameras.

EDIT 3:

Per comment from David Schwartz, camera models listed:

All Basler cameras:
(1)  Ace 2MP area scan, acA1600-60gm
(1)  Ace 5MP area scan, acA2500-20gm
(1)  Racer 2K linescan, raL2048-48gm
(2)  Racer 4K linescan, raL4096-24gm

Comment: "*The inputs need to have dedicated IP addresses, so I can't use a network switch into a single network port*"... sorry, what?  What does the number of physical ports connected on your PC have to do with the number of IP addresses on those ports?

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was that I need only one IP address on each port. Does that make the mud any clearer?...

Comment: Why on earth do you need that?  You will **still** need five addresses.  This question is accumulating downvotes, partly because it *makes no sense*.  I strongly suggest that you tell us your actual problem, instead of asking us how to implement the solution you've already decided upon (see also [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).

Comment: I have fallen prey to the XY problem before, because I am frequently learning about things of which I have little prior knowledge. But in this case, all I can say is that having each camera on a separate port is industry standard procedure. I will be able to give you a great answer in four months when this project is complete, just not right now!

Comment: The whole point of GigE cameras is that it's easy to interface many of them because the interface bandwidth is much higher than the camera needs. Can you tell us the make and model camera you're talking about?

Comment: Ack, just learned that comments don't support linebreaks? Added models to original question above.

Comment: In response to your edit above, **even if each camera requires a different subnet** you still don't need a NIC per camera.  I'm afraid I'm voting to close, as I think this question is fundamentally broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirements aren't clear at all: why exactly do you need multiple Gigabit Ethernet ports on the same computer to handle a bunch of IP cameras? You should probably revise your design.

Anyway, the answer to your question strongly depends on the card model. If it uses a standard bus, like PCI Express or plain old PCI, it will work fine on any motherboard. If it uses some sort of proprietary connector (which is not an unusual sight in servers), it will only work on a compatible server.

Comment: Thanks Massimo, even this helps. I revised my question to be clearer and to specify that I am using PCIe.

Comment: It *really* depends on the card model, we can't be any more precise than this.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I appreciate your comments.